# Put APK aplication on Google Play

Tags: android

When I try to put an APK on Google Play it says I need to signed my application.

I use Eclipse, and my structure files are the following:

> > My Project
>
> - Folder src
>
>   -> main.myproject
> - Folder gen
>
>   -> adapters.myproject
>
>   -> classes.myproject
>
>   -> com.myproject

How should I export signed application? If you say to me that the steps are:

> Right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed

, when I finish those steps I lose all items (except com.myproject) from my 'Folder Gen'. How's that possible?

I know how to Align APK. Yesterday I put my first application on Google Play. I did the Android Tools -> Export Signed thing (I've lost my files, but I had backup..), then I align the APK and send it to Google Play.

Today I want to update the APK in Google Play, I know I have to change the version, but what about the signed thing? Thanks.

**Edit: Solved.**

First problem: don't ever put your files into Gen folder, always use the SRC folder.
Second problem: because I put the files into Gen Folder, when compiled the files were deleted

Comment: Also, this page has everything you need: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I do lose the files. Whenever I Export as Signed they automatically get of my Eclipse Explorer files, and I receive immediatelly tons of errors because packages are missing.

Comment: I do have read that page and it's confusing..no images, no nothing. I'm trying to find more confortable tutorials.

Comment: Ok, I've signed the application and I have "lost" from Eclipse Explorer the files. Can you tell me how do I rebuild the application to create those files again?

Comment: Don't put anything in the gen folder!

Comment: @DídacPérez do you think that could be the problem I told to "Kailash Dabhi" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont panic about the **gen** folder as **Eclipse** is rebuilding the apk using your keystore.

1.increment the version code and right click on the project and select **Export**

2.then click on **Export Android Application**

3.Then use the **keystore which you have created to upload this app on Playstore**

4.And choose the destination to where you want to put the apk file and just publish it on playstore for backup.

***To install the signed apk***

1.open the  **command prompt(cmd)**

2.go to the **android sdk folder**

3.go to the **platform-tools folder**

4.then type adb install **path_to_your_APK**

That's it..enjoy!

Comment: Yes, that worked. I've another question, please tell me if I need to create another topic, I made everything correct (my APK works perfectly before signed/align it), after align it I tried to install directly in my device (without put on Google Play), after the installation when I execute the application I receive the error: "The application has stopped". How d'hell I'm going to know where is the error? Because, without align the APK it all works perfectly.